# How to describe something as a 'work in progress'

Tags: vocabulary

What's a good idiomatic way to tell a Chinese speaker that something is a 'work in progress' - as for example, "my Chinese language skills are still a work in progress'. Would it be similar to ‘还在进行的努力’ or is there a more idiomatic way to express the idea that I still need to do more work to complete my language skills? Thanks

Comment: You can say `还在努力中`.

Answer (score 3):

just say "还在修炼中”， this sounds humorous.

Answer (score 0):

`my Chinese language skills are still a work in progress`, it seems you are a beginner of Chinese, so this can be translated into `我的中文(汉语)还需要继续努力去学`

> `work in process`

if translated into Chinese directly, that is `还在进行的工作`, in Chinese `工作` means the `job`, that is the most important meaning, and there are some other meanings, but in English, all the thing you are doing can be describe as `工作` or `work`.So, in Chinese the `work` of `work in process` is `the level of you Chinese` or `the process of your Chinese learning`.

So, to sum up, it can be translated into `我的中文(汉语)还需要再接再厉`, and  `work in process` is `工作还在继续`, but in practical, you should know what the exactly the `work` is. Chinese Language is not a language that with strict language grammar, just enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where someone asks you about the progress of your language skill, you can say:

- 还在学
- or 还在努力
- or 还在用功

Exception:

On a CV, sometimes we use "work in progress" to describe the current position; in such case you can write 在读 if the position is academic.