# How can I say "work in progess"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm making a webpage and I want to put "work in progress" in mandarin.

Is there any idiomatic way to express this?

I saw [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/how-to-describe-something-as-a-work-in-progress), but I was in doubt if I could use this same expression in the context I want to say this.

Comment: you should specify if you expect to show this page mainly to Mainland users or not. You might want to use simplified or traditional characters (or both!) based on the target audience of your service

Answer (score 1):

本網頁仍在籌備中 - This webpage is under preparation.

網頁設計工程正在進行中 - The design/construction of the webpage is in progress.

Comment: If I want to say something like "Bitbucket (work in progress)", it's also right to say "Bitbucket(工作 进行中)"?

Comment: Unless you are making a webpage for Bitbucket, I wouldn't put its name as the subject, but make a reference to it. So you can say "網頁準備工作(經由Bitbucket的平台)正进行中" or "網頁準備工作(運用Bitbucket的軟件)正进行中". If you do make a webpage for it, then you may say "Bitbucket 的網頁正进行中".

Answer (score 0):

A website's name plus (work in progress) is not a very impactful statement.

The phrase "work in progress" implies "It is not good enough". Like saying "I am working on it, but I am not guaranteeing anything"

I presume the site owner was trying to say "we are actively working on the official launching of the site"

I suggest:

Bitbucket (即將到臨/ Coming soon) - *a solid promise*

Bitbucket (蓄勢待發/ Ready to launch) - *a strong promise*

If you must use "work in progress" then you can consider

Bitbucket (建設工作進行中/ work in progress) - *an unbonded promise*

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in your temporary.html:

网站正在建设，敬请期待。

If you are moving to a new ip, but not ready yet, you could try:

网站正在搬家。

in your temp.html

Advice I found useful: Put a link to a page that works, also in a 404.shtml. Very user friendly!

Answer (score 0):

The most seen translation should be 施工中 or 准备中 or 建设中 (Constructing, Preparing, Building) for a much closer match of "work in progress" and can often be seen in websites. Of course this can be used on its own in bold typography or along side with other too.

For instance, if you want to be a bit more formal it can be 当前网页正在施工中，尽情期待 (The current website is under construction, Please look forward to it)

To add a little flare you could even change the 中 to "Ing" (so same how it's used in English and people understand it) so 施工ing, 准备ing, 建设ing

Answer (score 0):

To simply express "The website is not available", you can say:
网站服务暂不可用！
And for "work in progress":
网站正在加急建设中，请过后再来！to let users know they can come later.\

Answer (score 0):

网页建设中，敬请期待
网页建设中tells people you are working on this website, while 敬请期待 ask browsers to wait and invite them check it out in a short future.

Answer (score -2):

I think 进行中 would be the best in this case.
Where 进行中 means "in progress"
and 这个网站正在进行中 would mean "This website is currently in progress"